# How to specify categorical features in cat boost?

Tags: machine-learning, binary-classification, ensemble-learning, categorical-data, boosting

I have a dataset (pandas data frame) with all features of type int32 containing continuous values except one feature `state_number`, its data type is int32, but it represents different states of a network (category). The feature `state_number` has 11 unique values. I want to train a cat boost model on this dataset; how can I specify in cat boost to treat it as a category even though it looks like a number? So far I have tried these steps:

1. Type cast `state_number` to category type for both train and test data.

   `X_train_['state_number'] = X_train_['state_number'].astype("category")`
2. While training cat boost, I specified the `state_number` in the `cat_feature` parameter.

   `model_catBoost.fit(X_train, y_train ,cat_features = ['state_number'])`

Is this approach correct, or am I adding some bias or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is this approach correct, or am I adding some bias or doing something wrong?**

You're approach is correct.

You are correct in thinking that the categorical variable `state_number` should not be treated as an ordinary numerical variable.  CatBoost offers functionality to handle categorical features.  Passing the column name `state_number` as an argument to the `cat_features` parameter within the `.fit()` method--as you have done--is a perfectly acceptable method (see [documentation](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostclassifier#cat_features)).